# Предложение по вопросам без ответа

Tags: предложение

Итак, есть существенная часть вопросов, по которым нет совсем ответа, либо нет принятого ответа. Что потеряет сообщество, если немного скорректировать в этой теме подход, а именно: увеличивать сумму репы отвечающему за принятый ответ в зависимости от прошедшего времени с появления вопроса? Лично у меня складывается впечатление, что вероятность появления ответа на вопрос прямо (или обратно) пропорциональна прошедшему времени. Более того, задающие имеют свойство теряться или терять интерес к своему вопросу со временем, уточнить или ответить в любом случае разумнее как можно скорее.

Можно предположить такие соображения участников, что на те вопросы, которые можно ответить итак отвечают. Отвечают чаще опытные участники и практически всегда оперативно и грамотно. Это прекрасно. А что, если увеличение вознаграждения (для тех кому оно интересно) подстегнет менее опытных участников браться за вопросы без ответов, причем по принципу "лучше сегодня - 20 и я, чем завтра - 25, но другой".

Возможно что-то важное из доводов мною упущено, минусы не замечены. Интересно мнение сообщества - опять же - плюсы, минусы.

Comment: Я сразу открою вопросы 11-го и 12-года и начну их окучивать %)

Comment: так прямо или обратно пропорциональна? если прямо - то нет никакого смысла поощрять ответы на старые вопросы - на них и так ответят - если обратно - то, наверное, стоит подвердить это выборкой с http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/

Comment: Есть много вопросов по которым нет принятого ответа, но есть работающие решения по сути. Есть вопросы которые  уже просто стали неактуальны.

Answer (score 4):

Было не мало споров даже про редактирование старых вопросов, приводящего к их всплытию на главной странице. У меня сложилось впечатление, что часть сообщества настроена против ворошения старых вопросов и появление в ленте вопросов 11-12 года раздражает не мало участников сообщества.

Как человек, любящий покопаться в не отвеченных вопросах прошлых лет, я проголосовал против вашего предложения и вот почему:

1. Во-первых вознаграждение есть - это медальки "Возрождение" и
   "Некромант". Не уверен, что они лучше/хуже кармы - все это
   виртуальные пузомерки, которые приятны, статусны, но по большому
   счет ничего не значат. Сегодня отвечающий в форме - завтра нет, карма же
   остается навсегда и не деградирует со временем, как могут
   деградировать знания отвечающего.
2. Во-вторых, если вопрос задан хорошо, на него ответ дается в
   считанные часы, если такой вопрос остался без внимания - его найдут
   и ответят. Любители медалек и старых вопросов, типа меня, его разыщут, можете не сомневаться. Как правило, в старых вопросов полно некорректных, неполных вопросов, по которым трудно воспроизвести
   ситуацию, или трудно дать компактный ответ, не покрывая десятки
   возможных вариантов и условий спрашивающего, о которых он не
   упомянул. Автора давно уже нет - уточнять не у кого.
3. В третьих, внимание лучше уделять новым вопросам, они актуальны,
   ответы на них спрашивающим нужны прямо сейчас. Быстрый, качественный
   ответ на новый вопрос приводит к тому, что в сообщество втягиваются
   свежие силы - оно растет и приводит к генерации новых качественных
   вопросов и ответов.

Поэтому вводя дополнительную мотивацию на работу со старыми вопросами, делая их более ценными, вы оттягиваете силы на некачественные старые вопросы, побуждая давать на них либо такие же некачественные ответы, либо многостраничные телеги фактически с несколькими ответами в которой каждый второй абзац будет начинаться с "Предположим у вас...".

Comment: очень аргументировано, спасибо